# Pandas Time Series normalize day wise

Tags: pandas, time-series, normalization, series

I want to normalize a time series on a daily base. 
Right now i have code as follows:

```
for date in set(df.index.date):
    print('Date: ' + str(date))
        df[df.index.date == date] = df[df.index.date == date].div(df[df.index.date == date].abs().max())
print('Normalization Done')
```

I works fine, but it is very slow. Do you know some better methods to do so?
Maybe some map function or list comprehension? Didn' figure out how to do so until now.

Comment: I think it could also work with itertools, but i am not skilled with this package.

Comment: doesn't `df.index = df.index.div(df.index.abs().max())` work? do you time components for the datetimes or just dates? it looks like you want to remove or nomarlise the datetimes to dates with 00:00:00 times first and then normalise the index?

Comment: I don't want to normalize/change the index. I want to normalize the values of the time series on a daily base. And for this use the index.date information.

Comment: So some form of groupby with division by that dates max or the max of the whole df?

Answer (score 0):

You can resample your dataframe to days, and sum all the values, that will give you a normalization value for each day. You can then resample that back to the index of your original dataframe, and simply divide.

The following line of code will do the trick:

```
df / df.resample('D').sum().asof(df.index)
```